# Does affinity colocation work with Ignite Thin client?

Tags: java, ignite

In [the docs](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/2.11.1/data-modeling/affinity-collocation) I could find examples of the affinity colocation config only for thick client. Does this feature works with thin client? Any config examples, please?

In my app I use key-value API to work with Ignite Cache.

I tried to simply make AffinityKey as a key of for my put/get operations (see code below). I used clientId to store values of a particular client on the same node. But performance testing didn't show any improvements with `getAll` timings.

I suspect that something is wrong with my configuration:

```
@Bean
    ClientConfiguration igniteThinClientConfiguration(IgniteProperties igniteProperties) {
        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
        clientConfiguration.setTimeout(igniteProperties.getTimeout());
        clientConfiguration.setAddresses(igniteProperties.getAddresses());
        clientConfiguration.setPartitionAwarenessEnabled(igniteProperties.isPartitionAwareness());
        return clientConfiguration;
    }
```

```
private static ClientCacheConfiguration cacheConfig(String cacheName, String cacheGroup, String dataRegion) {
        ClientCacheConfiguration cfg = new ClientCacheConfiguration();
        cfg.setName(cacheName);
        cfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
        cfg.setBackups(0);
        cfg.setExpiryPolicy(new TouchedExpiryPolicy(new Duration(TimeUnit.HOURS, 6)));
        cfg.setStatisticsEnabled(true);
        cfg.setDefaultLockTimeout(3000L);
        cfg.setGroupName(cacheGroup);
        cfg.setDataRegionName(dataRegion);
        return cfg;
    }
```

```
IgniteClient igniteClient = Ignition.startClient(igniteConfiguration);
ClientCache<AffinityKey<Long>, PaymentReceiptResponse> receiptCache = igniteClient.getOrCreateCache(cacheConfig(...));
...
receiptCache.put(new AffinityKey<>(123L, "clientId"), value)
...
Set<AffinityKey<String>> keys = ...;
receiptCache.getAll(keys)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, affinity colocation works in Ignite Thin Client the same way it does in thick client.

Thin client also supports [Partition Awareness](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/2.11.1/thin-clients/getting-started-with-thin-clients#partition-awareness) - sends requests directly to the primary node for the given cache entry. It is enabled by default.

> I tried to simply make AffinityKey as a key of for my put/get operations, but performance testing didn't show any improvements with timings.

`AffinityKey` does not improve the performance of `put` operation. `AffinityKey` controls data distribution and allows things like *"put all orders for the client on the same node where the client entry is stored"*, so that related data can be processed together (with Compute or SQL) - this is  where you can achieve performance improvement.

Comment: "put all orders for the client on the same node where the client entry is stored" - this is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. I use clientId as affinity key to store values related to a particular clients on the same node. In my performance test I tested only get operations, but no improvements. So I suspect that something is wrong with my client config.

Comment: You're just copying the data from the server to the client -- there is no benefit for the data being co-located. Where you get the benefit is where you _don't_ copy the data over the network. For example, you could add up the value of all the payments on the server-side (using compute or SQL), with no network access.